# Deciphering "old" (not that old, 40s) German handwriting

Tags: handwriting

I was browsing an old photo album to find out more about my ancestors from Breslau/Wroclaw. Although I speak German, I have trouble to decipher the handwriting. If someone can be helpful, even partially, I appreciate!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer will not be helpful for others with similar questions. It's a pure service request.

Comment: Could you provide a better photograph of the post card, without the reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be some rubbish there.
The writer is basically counting names and sending greetings,
there is no meaning to me. He seems to just count his friends (?)

Some names I can decipher:
Mrs. Rammer, born as Schramm

Fritz Meissner

Dr. Hans Meissner

Mother Helena, born as Klapper (?)

August Meisner

He seems to order persons by rooms they have, f.e. on the right side top it says

"for everybody [ ... ? ] in their rooms on the third floor".

(In germany the first floor is what in english would be the second one)

A Mrs. Hedel Krauser seems to have a new store door or something.
The letter seems to be adressed to Neurode if I decipher that correctly.
Neurode was a place in Schlesien, but since after WW2 the polish massacred nearly all germans living there, I guess it will be hard to find any traces left.

Sorry that I could not be of more help, 
this guy's handwriting surely is terrible.
Maybe you could find out more about the names of the persons,
they seem to be german, but not "typical" german names from that time....

EDIT:

I just so happened to have read that you are originated from Breslau, which would underline my suggestion that this card was send to guys from Schlesien.
I hope you can find some of your ancestors, history is a thrilling topic, although it is from a dark time between poland and germany. I am glad that we can live in peace today, my grandparents where driven from Schlesien too and settled down near Fulda, germany. Have a nice new year 2020

Comment: Thank you! In combination with nleanba's answer, this answers my question! I accept yours because of the details.

Answer (score 6):

Photo album:

Großelterliches Geschäft in Neurode (Grafschaft Glatz)

Text on the postcard (which explains who lived in the house and who are the persons depicted on the photo). It seems that the writer received the photo from Finni (= Josefine) Kammer.

Left side:

am 14.12.46

in Nordhorn v.

Finni Kammer geb. Schramm

aus Neurode erhalten

Geburtshaus v. Fritz Meisner

u. Sohn Dr. Hans Meisner.

Mutter v. ihm Helena geb.

Klapper heiratete dahin (?).

3 Stockwerke hoch.

August Meisner d. Vater

v. Kfm. Fritz Meisner

wohnten im 1. Stock.

Fritz Meisner im 2. Stock.

Right Side:

Fel. (?) Galle Lehrerin (?) die

vorderen Zimmer im

3 . Stock.

Die hinteren Zimmer bewohnten Krauses.

Hedel Krause steht in

der Ladentür. Neben ihr

der jetzige Firmen-

Inhaber Fritz Langer u.

Pächter.

Neurode

Ring 6 glaube ich

Haus gehört noch Meisners

mit 2 Erben (?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is the usge of *Kurrentschrift* or *(old) German cursive*, which has some weird letterforms.

This [Table on Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift#/media/Datei:Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.svg) might help, also for deciphering other notes.

Comment: Thank you! In combination with clockwork's answer, this answers my question!

Comment: It could also be Sütterlin which is similar to Kurrent. See https://ahnenforschungowl.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/der-kleine-unterschied-sutterlin-und-kurrentschrift/